# Spring AMQP @RabbitListener convert to origin object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I try to send a message based on a flatten MAP using Spring Boot and AMQP. The message should then be received using @RabbitListener and transfer it back to a MAP.

First I have nested json String and flat it and send it using the following code:

```
// Flatten the JSON String returned into a map 
        Map<String,Object> jsonMap = JsonFlattener.flattenAsMap(result);

rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ApplicationProperties.rmqExchange, ApplicationProperties.rmqTopic, jsonMap, new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("amqp_Key1", "wert1");
                message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("amqp_Key2", "Wert2");
                message.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
                return message;
            }
        });
```

So far so good.

On the receiving site I try to use a Listener and convert the message payload back to the Map as it was send before.

The problem ist that I have no idea how to do it. 
I receive the message with the following code:

```
      @RabbitListener(queues = "temparea")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message) {


      log.info("Receiving data from RabbitMQ:");
      log.info("Message is of type: " + message.getClass().getName());
      log.info("Message: " + message.toString());   
    }
```

As I mentioned before I have no idea how I can convert the message to my old MAP. The __ TypeId __ of the Message is: com.github.wnameless.json.flattener.JsonifyLinkedHashMap

I would be more than glad if somebody could assist me how I get this message back to an Java Map.

BR

---

Update after answer from Artem Bilan:

I added the following code to my configuration file:

```
    @Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
  factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
  factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
  return factory;
}
```

But still I have no idea how to get the Map out of my message. 
The new code block does not change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` bean and Spring Boot will pick it up for the `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` bean definition which is used to build listener containers for the `@RabbitListener` methods.

**UPDATE**

Pay attention to the [Spring AMQP JSON Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/spring-rabbit-json).

There is a bean like `jsonConverter()`. According Spring Boot auto-configuration this bean is injected to the default:

```
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
```

Which is really used for the `@RabbitListener` by default, when the `containerFactory` attribute is empty.

So, you need just configure that bean and don't need any custom `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`. Or if you do that you should specify its bean name in that `containerFactory` attribute of your `@RabbitListener` definitions.

Another option to consider is like `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.setTypePrecedence()`:

```
/**
 * Set the precedence for evaluating type information in message properties.
 * When using {@code @RabbitListener} at the method level, the framework attempts
 * to determine the target type for payload conversion from the method signature.
 * If so, this type is provided in the
 * {@link MessageProperties#getInferredArgumentType() inferredArgumentType}
 * message property.
 * <p> By default, if the type is concrete (not abstract, not an interface), this will
 * be used ahead of type information provided in the {@code __TypeId__} and
 * associated headers provided by the sender.
 * <p> If you wish to force the use of the  {@code __TypeId__} and associated headers
 * (such as when the actual type is a subclass of the method argument type),
 * set the precedence to {@link TypePrecedence#TYPE_ID}.
 * @param typePrecedence the precedence.
 * @since 1.6
 * @see DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper#setTypePrecedence(Jackson2JavaTypeMapper.TypePrecedence)
 */
public void setTypePrecedence(Jackson2JavaTypeMapper.TypePrecedence typePrecedence) {
```

So, if you want still to have a `Message` as a method argument but get a gain of the JSON conversion based on the `__TypeId__` header, you should consider to configure `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` to be based on the `Jackson2JavaTypeMapper.TypePrecedence.TYPE_ID`.

Comment: Did you have an idea or a code example how to do it. I read about this. But I have no clue how to configure the message converter to ensure that it will return the original Map which was send.

Comment: Code Update see original post